# Typedef function vs function pointer

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, declaration

I'm trying to understand function declaration using typedefs.

What does this code do in C++?

```
typedef void fcn_t(void);
typedef void (*ptr_t)(void);

fcn_t f;
fcn_t *pf;
ptr_t pf2;
```

In my understanding:

- `fcn_t` is the type of a function, and so the line with `f` is a function *declaration* (not a definition), and I could later define it like `void f(void) { blabla(); bleble(); }` just as if I had declared `void f(void);` instead of `fcn_t f;`;
- `fcn_t *` is the type of a function pointer, and the line with `pf` is a pointer variable *definition*, and `pf` is default-initialized (assuming the code excerpt is from the global scope);
- There is no difference between `fcn_t*` and `ptr_t`, thus everything I said about `pf` applies to `pf2`.

Did I get it right? Would any of the three declarations have its meaning changed if I marked them `extern`? What would change if the code was compiled as C instead of as C++?

Comment: where did you define `ptr_f`?

Comment: btw I strongly suggest the following tutorial: http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi

Comment: 1. yes, 2. `pf` is initialized to null pointer (if at global scope), 3.yes  4. using `extern` on `pf` would make it a declaration and not a definition. 5. C and C++ are usually compiled, not interpreted

Comment: @arboreal84 typo, corrected it. And thanks, will look at that tutorial!

Comment: You should prefer [alias declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to typedefs.

Comment: @RawN I know! I'm using typedefs because this I'm putting these inside `extern "C" {}`

Comment: @M.M I meant "interpreted" as in english, not as in computer science hehe, but ok, I changed the wording

Comment: I don't see real benefit of `fcn_t typedef`.  I understand that  function pointer can be used as an alternative name to call the function.  But what is the purpose of `fcn_t typedef`?

Comment: @Nguaial - If you give the type a descriptive name, then forward declaring those functions with `fcn_t` documents their purpose right at the top of the source file. So you know that those will be passed as callbacks to library X without having to look for the code that registers them.  Furthermore, you can have `std::function<fcn_t>` parameters. Again being more descriptive than `std::function<Ret(Arg1, Arg2)>`. To summarize, it can have great boons for code readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are right on all three counts.  The only thing that would change if you marked them `extern` are the function pointers.  Function declarations are by default `extern` in C++.

Try and compile the following program

```
template <typename...>
struct WhichType;

typedef void fcn_t(void);
typedef void (*ptr_t)(void);

// constexpr auto one = WhichType<fcn_t>{};
// constexpr auto two = WhichType<fcn_t*>{};
// constexpr auto three = WhichType<ptr_t>{};

fcn_t f;

void f() {}

int main() {
    f();
}
```

Uncommenting the commented lines will likely give you a compiler error that tells you what types the `WhichType` instance is being instantiated with, and as a result it should show you the exact types of all three things you asked about.  It's a trick I picked up from Scott Meyers' book "Effective Modern C++".

---

To test whether the declarations are extern or not, write two simple implementation files, with one containing the definition of the variable

**main.cpp**

```
template <typename...>
struct WhichType;

typedef void fcn_t(void);
typedef void (*ptr_t)(void);

fcn_t f;

int main() {
    f();
}
```

**definition.cpp**

```
void f() {}
```

and then compile, link and run `definition.cpp` and `main.cpp` (via `g++ -std=c++14 definition.cpp main.cpp` and then `./a.out`).  If the declaration was not extern then the compile would fail with an undefined symbol error.

Comment: I tried it! I just wanted to know if this was standard C++ or my GCC was just being nice to me :)

Comment: @fonini - It's standard C++ (and C coincidentally)

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple illustration of these `typedef`

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void fcn_t(void);
typedef void (*ptr_t)(void);

fcn_t f;
fcn_t *pf;
ptr_t pf2;

void
f(void)
{
  printf("I am void\n");
}

void 
vSayHi(void)
{
   printf( "Hi\n" );
}

int
main(void)
{

   pf2 = vSayHi;
   pf2();

   pf = vSayHi;
   pf();

   f();

   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Hi
Hi
I am void
```